# Java SimpleDateFormat parse not reversibile?

Tags: java, parsing, date, format

I am trying to parse a date format string and then print out the formatted string for the same pattern. I am expecting them to be the same. But the output is not agreeing with the input. Any help is much appreciated

Here is my code

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String pattern=args[0];
    String dtstr = args[1];
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    Date date = new Date();
    try {
        //
        String fmtd = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println("The formatted string: " +fmtd);
        System.out.println("The parsed date is: " + sdf.format(sdf.parse(fmtd)));
        System.out.println("The parsed date from input is: " + sdf.format(sdf.parse(dtstr)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is how I invoke this

`JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/  sudo java Test "EEE MMM dd YYYY HH:mm:ss Z (zzzz)" "Sun Sep 22 2013 20:03:46 +0530 (India Standard Time)"`

Here is the output

```
The formatted string: Wed Sep 25 2013 19:55:57 +0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
The parsed date is: Wed Jan 02 2013 19:55:57 +0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
The parsed date from input is: Sun Dec 30 2013 20:03:46 +0530 (India Standard Time)
```

I am expecting the `formatted string` and the `parsed strings` to be identical
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `YYYY` in your format string. It should be `yyyy`:

```
"EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss Z (zzzz)";
```

`Y` is for [Week Year](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#week_year):

> A week year is in sync with a `WEEK_OF_YEAR` cycle. All weeks between
>   the first and last weeks (inclusive) have the same week year value.
>   Therefore, **the first and last days of a week year may have different
>   calendar year values.**
>
> For example, January 1, 1998 is a `Thursday`. If `getFirstDayOfWeek()` is
>   `MONDAY` and `getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()` is 4 (ISO 8601 standard
>   compatible setting), then week 1 of 1998 starts on December 29, 1997,
>   and ends on January 4, 1998. The week year is 1998 for the last three
>   days of calendar year 1997. If, however, `getFirstDayOfWeek()` is
>   `SUNDAY`, then week 1 of 1998 starts on January 4, 1998, and ends on
>   January 10, 1998; the first three days of 1998 then are part of week
>   53 of 1997 and their week year is 1997.

With the changed pattern, you will get following output:

```
The formatted string: Thu Sep 26 2013 01:32:09 +0530 (India Standard Time)
The parsed date is: Thu Sep 26 2013 01:32:09 +0530 (India Standard Time)
The parsed date from input is: Sun Sep 22 2013 20:03:46 +0530 (India Standard Time)
```